# reset the Select2 dropdowns on Ajax Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

im using jquery select2 library

```
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
```

Problem i am facing, i have multiple dropdowns in my form and if i submit the form through Ajax all feilds do get reset/empty except the select2 dropdowns..

i use this for the reset

```
$("#block-validate")[0].reset();
```

and it works perfectly fine and reset/empty all the fields in the form except the select2

i know there is a way to clear the the feild of select2 using this

```
$("#e8").select2("val", "");
```

But it will only reset the value for the intended select2. i mean we can do like this

```
$("#e8, #e9, #e10, #e11").select2("val", "");
```

what i am trying to say is there any way to reset/empty all the form fields including the select2 dropdowns without specifically calling there ID's.

or even just a code to reset or empty all the dropdowns for select2 without specifically calling there ID's, just all the Select2 dropdowns go reset on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements that are initialized with select2 get the class `select2-offscreen`.

So, to avoid resetting all select2 elements with their IDs you could do the following

```
jQuery('.select2-offscreen').select2('val', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Select2 4.0.3

```
$('.select2').val('').trigger("change");
```